# Hibernate into a GPars pool

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, gpars

I am trying to find an object (instance of Worker) but it is not retreived inside a Gpars pool.

```
    List<Responsable> responsables = Responsable.list()
    withPool(20) {
        responsables.eachParallel { Responsable responsable ->
            Responsable.withNewTransaction { session ->
                Worker.withNewTransaction {
                    Worker worker = Worker.findByIdBddt(responsable.reference)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Before the pool, a Worker.list() give me all instances of this class, but inside the pool, the result size is 0, and of course, the dynamic finder does not give any result.